# Where to begin for create 2d water?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I want to create 2d water in Unity engine. Can you take me advice, where to begin? This is a example of 2d water https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBWwNHEHo3I . Thanks advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with a shader utilizing a GrabPass. You'll need to make a quad where the water is, then apply a material with a shader to the quad. The shader should have a GrabPass, and then a pass that vertically flips and distorts the GrabPass. One example of such a shader is below ([source](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1149814/view.html)):

```
Shader "Custom/WaterGrab" 
{
    Properties 
    {        
        _Colour ("Colour", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Noise text", 2D) = "bump" {}
        _Magnitude ("Magnitude", Range(0,1)) = 0.05
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Opaque"}
        ZWrite On Lighting Off Cull Off Fog { Mode Off } Blend One Zero

        GrabPass { "_GrabTexture" }

        Pass 
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            sampler2D _GrabTexture;
            fixed4 _Colour;
            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float  _Magnitude;

            struct vin
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float4 color : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;

            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                fixed4 color : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 uvgrab : TEXCOORD1;

            };

            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            // Vertex function 
            v2f vert (vin v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                o.color = v.color;
                o.texcoord = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);


            #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
                float scale = -1.0;
            #else
                float scale = 1.0;
            #endif            

                o.uvgrab.xy = (float2(o.vertex.x, (o.vertex.y)* scale) + o.vertex.w) * 0.5;
                o.uvgrab.zw = o.vertex.zw;

                float4 top = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, float4(0, 0.5, 0, 1));
                top.xy /= top.w;

                o.uvgrab.y = 1 - (o.uvgrab.y + top.y);

                return o;
            }

            // Fragment function
            half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
            {        

                half4 bump = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord );
                half2 distortion = UnpackNormal(bump).rg;


                i.uvgrab.xy += distortion * _Magnitude;                    
                fixed4 col = tex2D( _GrabTexture, i.uvgrab);                
                return col * _Colour;
            }

            ENDCG
        } 
    }
}
```

In shaders like this, you'll need to provide a bump map that tells the water how to distort the GrabPass. In the above example, it should be inserted as the `_MainTex` texture. It should look something like this:
[image]